# Is there a way to create a TZipfile without including the directory structure of the original files?

Tags: delphi

The title says it all.

I want to create an anonymous Zip file using TZipFile class with simply the file names and no directory structure as it will be distributed to third parties. Reading through all the responses here and the TZipFile documentation I cannot see a way to do it.

Comment: The obvious way is to use [TZipFile.Add](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Zip.TZipFile.Add) for each file to be added to archive. What prevents you from doing that?

Comment: I am doing that but the end result is that when I open the archive, I see the full path of the original files,  I want all the files to appear at the root.

Comment: When you add a file to archive using `FileName` and omit the second parameter (`ArchiveFileName`) it is defaulted to `ExtractFileName(FileName)` as per documentation. All path information is stripped and it works as expected. Could you show us your code or provide [mcve]?

Comment: Ok, I was adding from stream but had used the original filename as the archive file name.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Do not specify `ArchiveFileName` parameter of [`Add()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Zip.TZipFile.Add) method:

> ArchiveFileName is the full path of the file in the archive. If the parameter is not specified, the default value is ExtractFileName(FileName).

```
  with TZipFile.Create do
    try
      Open('D:\MyZipFile.zip', zmWrite);
      Add('D:\SomeFileToAdd.ext');
    finally
      Free;
    end;
```

This way, you'll find `SomeFileToAdd.ext` instead of `D:\SomeFileToAdd.ext`.

Comment: Alternatively one could explicitly specify ArchiveFileName without a path. That would make it obvious.